# Passing Variable to NR in AWK command not working

Tags: shell, unix, awk, ksh

Hi I'm trying to print the 5 lines after a regular expression has been found using the awk command. I have the following:

```
line_start=$(awk '/regex/{print NR}' file)
let line_end=$line_start+4
awk 'NR==$line_start, NR==$line_end' file
```

This does not print anything. It doesnt hang, just goes on the next line.

I researched some similar problems, and saw people use the -v option. Am I supposed to use that here, their situations were for larger awk scripts.

By the way, I am using Kornshell

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are several problems with your script. The immediate problem is that in the second call to awk, you use single quotes around the script, so `$line_start` and `$line_end` are *not* variables expanded by the shell, instead they're passed literally as part of the script to awk. You can fix this by using double quotes instead.

```
awk "NR==$line_start, NR==$line_end" file
```

This works only because `$line_start` and `$line_end` are numbers. If they were strings, you couldn't do this, because the values of the shell variables end up being parsed by awk as part of awk code, not as strings. In general, to pass a string to an awk script, you can use the idiom with `-v` to define awk variables with the same name as the shell variables (or with different names if you prefer):

```
awk -v "line_start=$line_start" -v "line_end=$line_end" 'NR==line_start, NR==line_end' file
```

There are more problems with your script.

- You parse the file twice. This can be slow if the file is large, and it is impossible if the data comes from a pipe instead of a disk file.
- If there is more than one match for `/regex/`, then `$line_start` will contain a list of line numbers. The shell will complain of a syntax error on the `let` line.

If you want to show 5 lines following a match, do the counting inside awk.

```
awk '
  /regex/ { show_lines = 5 }
  show_lines { print; --show_lines; }
' file
```

If you only want to show the first matching block, exit once `show_lines` reaches 0.

```
  show_lines { print; --show_lines; if (!show_lines) exit; }
```

Comment: Wow! you guys are awesome thanks a lot! I didn't have all of this info available. Very detailed answer thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use sed for this:

```
sed -n '/regex/{N;N;N;N;N;p}' file
```

Or change the awk solution:

```
line_start=$(awk '/regex/{print NR}' file) 
let line_end=$line_start+4 
awk "{ if (NR>=$line_start && NR<=$line_end) print; }" file
```

Another awk solution `(s.awk)`:

```
BEGIN           { v = -1} 
/regex/         { v = 0 } 
v > -1          { v++   }
v > -1 && v < 5 { print }
v == 5          { exit  }
```

use:

```
awk -f s.awk file
```

Comment: In most cases in the code you posted, `if` isn't necessary. Just put the condition outside the action block. This is what the OP tried to do and what Gilles does in his answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I understand a lot more now!